# OpenLDAP configuration

Tags: openldap, centos6

I try to install OpenLDAP in Centos 6. Installation is successful. But everytime I try to add user use below command, LDAP ask me to put a password.

> ldapadd -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=adminmart,dc=com" -W -f  /etc/openldap/root.ldif

Where can I get the password? In installation step, it not asking for set any password for LDAP.

> Enter LDAP Password:
>   ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)

Comment: Off topic: belongs on serverfault.co.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to generate password using below command

```
       slappasswd
```

run above command on console after that copy that input in slapd.conf after that restart ldap.

Answer (score 0):

The Manager password should be defined in slapd.conf or slapd.d. And you shouldn't be using that account anyway. It's for slapd, not for you.